# When should I use a MySQL TEXT field instead of a file?

Tags: mysql, file

Is there any advantage in using a **file** to store a long piece of text (say, a lengthy blog article), over a **MySQL TEXT**-type field? In my mind, I would imagine having retrieving the file through your program (PHP) being much quicker than bothering MySQL with fetching it for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say there are advantages either way, and it's just up to your specific situation. For example:

Using a text database field means that your blog entries are all contained in your database, making it easier to back up and move. It also means that you will not have to worry about file access, things like security, file locks, file names, etc. Also, you can query the data without writing any special code.

Using files instead also has benefits. It keeps your database small, especially when dealing with a lot of files. It allows the data to be accessed easily by other people, programs or machines with no database access. And you can easily transfer the files to another location if you need to reorganize your disks.

So it's totally up to your environment. Personally, unless you're dealing with a huge number of files, or huge files, I'd probably stick with the database option. It's just easier to deal with in most cases.

Comment: Very insightful! Thanks! I never thought about the number of files, that would definitely play a huge role in the decision.

Answer (score 2):

Use "char" and friends for short strings, for "structured" data you're likely to search for just as you would a number or a date.  Otherwise, use "text" where you'd want to do *full-text* searching against a large number of *unstructured* text data.  Like blogs ;)

Here's a good article:

http://devzone.zend.com/26/using-mysql-full-text-searching/

If you're only storing large amounts of text - if you don't actually want to *search* it with mySql, then storing the file externally has the same tradeoffs as storing .mp3 audio files or .png images externally.  In general, I'd prefer to store large "blobs" on the filesystem, rather than in the database.

IMHO...

===================================================

ADDENDUM:

In case there's any doubt in your mind - I'm suggesting that storing your blogs as "Text" in the database is probably the better option here.  The database is better at storing a large number of small entities (blog entries), and you have the added benefit getting full-text searches essentially "for free".

IMHO..

Comment: PPS: Another good link:  [To BLOB or Not To BLOB:
Large Object Storage in a Database or a Filesystem?](http://arxiv.org/ftp/cs/papers/0701/0701168.pdf)  "The study indicates that if objects are larger than
one megabyte on average, the file system has a clear
advantage. If the objects are under 256 kilobytes, the
database has a clear advantage."

Comment: I don't plan on performing full-text searches, but I'm saving the link for good reference. I agree with the latter bit; it seems to be the only reason I would want to keep it in a database, thus my question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

No advantage at all and will introduce bugginess if improperly coded.  Many cms systems use databases for a reason as they are designed to store and retrieve data like this more efficiently than files. If it were a better idea, Drupal, Joomla, Wordpress, etc would use files instead of databases.  Now if you're talking about images, then yes it's better to store on the filesystem, but even if you wrote a 10,000 word blog, you're talking about minimal size.

Comment: That's a good point, I didn't consider what other software uses -- and they seem to work so effeciently.